# What does "get someone in the guts" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "inspire someone"?

It would be the same thing. It would be, Find a passion, you know - Joseph Campbell said follow your bliss. Find something that absolutely gets you in the gut. Everything else comes if you’re really passionate about it. You’ll work the hours, do what it takes because you love what you’re doing. And you’ll probably live a lot longer.

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jimclash/2017/04/18/peter-buffett-warrens-youngest-son-says-growing-up-buffett-was-nothing-fancy/#7263da7d6506

Comment: I would say that "something that absolutely gets you in the gut" means here something that completely captivates you, absorbs you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In informal speech, [gut](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gut?q=gut%20feeling) is usually used to indicate an emotional, rather than an intellectual, response to something, for example:

> gut feeling: intuition
>   gut reaction: initial feeling
>   gut-wrenching: deeply disturbing

The text that you quoted is not a standard idiom: the speaker probably meant something that you can be emotionally involved with. Earlier he uses the word **passion**, which fits with this interpretation.